# Spotify WebAPI '/v1/me/player' best practices

Tags: spotify

I'm looking for advice about using '/v1/me/player' to get the Currently Playing Context. Obviously the endpoint gathers the current status of the media playing device but it seems to me that you would have to query it every few seconds or even more to keep up with the state of the track and device.

Is that really the intent?